# Re sizing DataGridView according to its content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, resize

I was looking to re size DataGridView according to its content. Because data source of grid view may have different size depending upon the data in it.I found resizing DataGridview according to Form size, but no way to re size DataGridView according to its content.
Any one have some idea?
[image]

Comment: You can resize individual columns according to their content. Surely it would be better to keep the resizing of the actual grid bound to the form size?

Comment: try `datagridview.AutoResizeColumns()`

Comment: @Asfk dv.AutoResizeColumns() will ony auto resize columns according to content, I want DataGridView to be auto resized according to its whole content. Is there a way??

Comment: @ghulam_ali what you mean in "whole content" can you add a picture please?

Comment: @Asfk I have edited my question with picture. There you can see blank space

Comment: not sure, but maybe this: DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use **Anchor** property to anchor your form elements to form borders.
I made a example form to illustrate it. There is a groupBox with some random controls and dataGridView with a many columns:

[image: Example form with DataGridView and some random controls]

Here are the Anchor setting for the form elements:

[image]

Now, when i load the form, I calculate the total width of dataGridView columns and increase the from width accordingly:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalWidth = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            totalWidth += col.Width;

        //assign Form1.width (add 100 extra pixels for borders etc.)
        this.Width = totalWidth + groupBox1.Width + 100;
    }
```

Comment: This a constant for spacing between border and form elements and also for the first empty column (marked with the star on the image). You can variate depending on what kind other element you have on the form.